# Is it possible to get a callback when data fed into a Play Concurrent.unicast Enumerator's channel has been processed?

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, enumerator

I'm proxying between a TCP connection and a WebSocket, and I want to apply back-pressure to the TCP socket if the WebSocket is sending data to the browser slowly. When I receive data from the TCP socket I do:

```
channel.push(data.toArray)
```

I'd like to get an acknowledgement of when that data has been sent. How do I get that?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this:

```
val resumer = Enumeratee.map[Array[Byte]] { in =>
    connection ! Tcp.ResumeReading
    in
}

val enumeratorWithAck = enumerator &> resumer
```

It seems to work, but is it the right way to do it?